# What are the pushouts and coequalizers in Hausdorff spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, morphism

Does the category of Hausdorff spaces have pushouts and coequalizers? I know that if we have pushouts and an initial object we have coequalizers, but do we have pushouts in this category?

Comment: Yes. Colimits of Hausdorff spaces are Hausdorffizations of colimits of spaces: https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Hausdorffization

Comment: (because left adjoints commute with colimits)